# So much has come between us

Tags: riddle

> I am better than my sister in every way!
>
> For example, I am better at math. When it comes to rounding I get the correct answer more than half the time, while she gets the correct answer less often.
>
> I even have my own fan base.
>
> Sometimes I wear tights, but not my sister. She is sometimes covered in mites! Gross!
>
> Maybe I'm just jealous though. My sister she is strong and can usually stand on her own, but I always seem to need support lest I fall to her level.

**Who am I?**

**Who is my sister?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you and your sister are

> *ceiling* and *floor*, respectively.

*For example, I am better at math. When it comes to rounding I get the correct answer more than half the time, while she gets the correct answer less often.*

> For numbers with finitely many decimal places, and if you use the convention that things ending with exactly a 5 get rounded up, ceiling(x)=round(x) more often than floor(x)=round(x).

*I even have my own fan base.*

> Ceiling fans.

*Sometimes I wear tights, but not my sister. She is sometimes covered in mites! Gross!*

> Ceilings have stalac*tites* and floors have stalag*mites*.

*Maybe I'm just jealous though. My sister she is strong and can usually stand on her own, but I always seem to need support lest I fall to her level.*

> A ceiling without walls to support it would be in a lot of trouble.

Comment: Good Job! This is exactly right.

Comment: @YoungJohn Nitpick: [there are many modes of rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_the_nearest_integer) and lots of them do not round to +∞. In fact at least 2 of the commonly used ones (round half away from 0/round half to nearest even) have an equal distribution of round half up/down depending on your number range. It's not necessary (or even true!) that rounding up happens more than rounding down.

Comment: Yup. You'll notice that I was *quite specific* in what I said about that bit :-).